# Writing angle brackets to file produces codes

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am creating an XML file and writing the elements in VB.NET 2017 on a machine with a German OS. I am using the xml writer class and when I use the following the start and end tags of the element show correctly in my file:

```
.WriteStartElement("conceptGrp")
.WriteString(dataLine)
.WriteEndElement()
```

I am extracting child elements from an existing XML file and inserting them into element using the variable "dataLine". But the angle brackets around the tags in dataLine are being displayed as "&lt" and "&gt" in the file I have created. This is causing an error when I read the data into other software.

In Visual Basic in the Output pane, Locals window and Watch window all of the content of the variable "dataLine" is being displayed as it should be.

How can I correct the data I am writing to file.

Ben

Comment: WriteString does this because it expects the argument to be only string information, not XML data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring(v=vs.110).aspx
Try WriteRaw instead

Comment: What about `WriteElementString`?

Comment: The data you are receiving was sent via html which the angle brackets are special characters.  So you need to decode the html data using  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteString` is designed to write plain string information into a tag (as content, presumably) From the [WriteString docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

> WriteString does the following:
>
> ```
> The characters &, <, and > are replaced with &amp;, &lt;, and &gt;, respectively.
> ```

Instead, you could use the `WriteRaw` method ([WriteRaw docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0755ytay(v=vs.110).aspx)) which can write raw XML. Although, maybe you should consider parsing the incoming object first to properly guarantee the output format which you will be writing?

Comment: I tried using WriteRaw and it produces exactly the same results.

What's puzzling me is that the lines '.WriteStartElement' and '.WriteEndElement' correctly produce the angle brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I couldn't get a successful result from my first attempt so I scrapped that part of the code and rewrote it from scratch using `WriteRaw` then it worked fine. Thanks to all of you guys for the advice you gave, it is certainly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WriteElementString`, check the following example :

```
    writer.WriteStartElement("ns", "cusotmer", "www.diranieh.com")
    writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", "A")
    writer.WriteElementString("LastName", "B")
    writer.WriteEndElement()
```

which produces the following result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ns:cusotmer xmlns:ns="www.diranieh.com">
  <FirstName>A</FirstName>
  <LastName>B</LastName>
</ns:cusotmer>
```

extra info can be found here :
http://diranieh.com/NETXML/XmlWriter.htm

Comment: I am away for a couple of days so I will try out the suggestions over the weekend. I didn't want to appear rude and just duck away.